# CSS - the content protrudes outside the main frame

Tags: css

I have problem with the CSS. I'm changing dynamically one div's content. The problem is, it protrudes outside the main frame, as below:

[image]

This's the result I expect. How to achieve that ?

[image]

### Edit

[jsFiddle's code](http://jsfiddle.net/aHTUQ/)

Comment: We'll need a little more to go on. The CSS and HTML would be good. A reduction posted on jsFiddle.net would be better.

Comment: Try it : {height:auto;
max-height:none;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give maxwidth to your div:

```
div 
{
 max-width: 100px;//The width of your div
}
```

Comment: it helps, but there is also the height case. Setting the max-height doesn't change anything

Comment: You can use : oveflow:auto; And then If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content

Comment: nope, the problem still remained. I've attached the jsFiddle's code

Comment: OK, after adding the height:auto; the problem has been fixed. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

use `word-wrap:break-word` for the container element